# Для чего нужен Dropout в машинном обучении?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

Для чего используют Dropout в машинном обучении? Как это влияет на скорость обучения, выходные данные?

Какие есть примеры практического применения Dropout? В каких случаях его нужно использовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Большинство ссылок гугла выдаёт [определение вроде такого](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8)):

> Исключение или **дропаут** (от англ. dropout) — метод **регуляризации**
> искусственных нейронных сетей, предназначен **для уменьшения
> переобучения сети** за счет предотвращения сложных коадаптаций отдельных
> нейронов на тренировочных данных во время обучения.

Использовать его нужно, если вы видите, что происходит переобучение - на тренировочной выборке сеть хорошо учится, а на тестовых/отложенных данных показывает плохой скор. Чтобы бороться с этим эффектом применяют в частности дропаут. Модель при этом хуже учится на тренировочных данных, но зато показывает лучше результат на тестовых/отложенных данных, чем был без дропаута.

Обучение при этом может идти медленнее, но нужно помнить, что на скорость обучения влияет множество параметров, и если вы меняете один параметр, вероятно нужно будет менять и другие, и как всё это вместе скажется на скорости и качестве обучения заранее обычно нельзя сказать.

Насчёт примеров конкретных не приведу, но если данных много и в них нет чёткого однозначного сигнала из-за чего модель переобучается на часть данных и плохо генерализует общую совокупность, в этом случае применяют дропаут.

Answer (score 4):

Dropout - один из методов регуляризации (борьбы с переобучением модели). Суть `dropout` в "забывании" части информации. Т.е. некоторый, заданный заранее процент нейронных связей, разрывается (забывается) на выходе из текущего слоя нейронной сети. Таким образом вместо того, чтобы идеально подобрать веса только лишь для обучающего набора данных, НС учится подбирать ответ для похожих данных, которые не встречались в обучающем наборе. Это может значительно улучшить точность сети для данных, которые не встречались в обучающем наборе.

При применении `dropout`, обучение может длиться дольше.